# CTE using criteria api with Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I've read that CTE is now supported in hibernate (6.02).
Didnt find an example or manual of how using it with criteria api.

For example the following (not interesting) sql query where tbl1 is an entity.
`with tbl as (select col1 from tbl2)  select col1 from tble`

Didnt find any related examples.